# Python only prints to one cell in a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, pyqt5

I am trying to make a print button for a GUI I am making. Right now when I click the print button it will store all the data to one cell for each variable I am trying to print. Right now I am trying to print the time, rpms, torque, and horsepower. It will give me each of those in their own separate cell, but it will not start a new row. With in this cell the format is: [1,2,3,4,5,...]. The brackets are in the cells as well. I would like for them to be separated into rows that way the user of the GUI can take the data for post processing. What I have mostly found on this matter is people are trying to get words into different cells and I know that characters act differently than numbers, pr that people want the values to be in a single cell, not the opposite like in my case.

What I have right now is that the print button will print a file with a unique time stamp. That way the users can keep this data for safe keeping.

Thank You in advance!

```
"""
SCSU DYNO GUI PROGRAM

created 11/10/2017

"""


import sys
import time
from time import gmtime, localtime, strftime

import csv
import numpy as np
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread,QTimer, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox,QWidget, QApplication,QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random
from DynoTest1 import Ui_DynoTest1


__author__ = 'Matt Munn'

pg.setConfigOption('background', None)
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

class GetData(QThread):
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)

    #Distance = 0.5 #This is dependent on the lever arm.

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        arduino_ports = [  # automatically searches for an Arduino and selects the port it's on
            p.device
            for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
            if 'Arduino' in p.description
        ]

        if not arduino_ports:
            raise IOError("No Arduino found - is it plugged in? If so, restart computer.")
        if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
            warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')
        self.Arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0], 9600, timeout=1)

    def __del__(self):  # part of the standard format of a QThread
        self.wait()

    def run(self):  # also a required QThread function, the working part
        self.Arduino.close()
        self.Arduino.open()

        self.Arduino.flush()
        self.Arduino.reset_input_buffer()
        start_time = time.time()

        Distance = 1 #This is dependent on the lever arm.
        Max_RPM = 0
        Max_Horsepower = 0
        Max_Torque = 0
#This is what does the work to get the data from the arduino and then converts it to the other needed values.
        while True:
            while self.Arduino.inWaiting() == 0:
                pass
            try:
                data = self.Arduino.readline()
                dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
                self.Arduino.reset_input_buffer()
                Force = round(float(dataarray[0]), 3)
                RPM = round(float(dataarray[1]), 0)
                if Max_RPM < RPM:
                    Max_RPM = RPM
                Torque = round(Force * Distance, 2)
                if Max_Torque < Torque:
                    Max_Torque = Torque
                Horsepower = round(Torque * RPM / 5252, 2)
                if Max_Horsepower < Horsepower:
                    Max_Horsepower = Horsepower
                Run_Time = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
                print(Force, 'Grams', ",", RPM, 'RPMs', ",", Torque, "ft-lbs", ",", Horsepower, "hp", Run_Time,
                      "Time Elasped")
                self.dataChanged.emit(Force, RPM, Max_RPM, Torque, Max_Torque, Horsepower, Max_Horsepower, Run_Time)
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit, IndexError, ValueError):
                pass


class GUI(QWidget, Ui_DynoTest1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, border = None):
# This is what is used to make the graph.        
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = GetData(self)
        self.thread.dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)
        self.thread.start()
        self.rpm = []
        self.torque = []
        self.horse_power = []
        self.time = []
        self.counter = 0

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.plot.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.graphicsView.setLayout(layout)

        self.p1 = self.plot.plotItem
        self.p1.setLabels(left='Torque (ft-lbs)', bottom= 'Time (sec)')
        self.TorqueCurve = self.p1.plot()
        self.TorqueCurve.setPen(pg.mkPen(QColor(0,0,0), width=2.5))

        self.p2 = pg.ViewBox()
        self.HorsePowerCurve = pg.PlotCurveItem()
        self.HorsePowerCurve.setPen(pg.mkPen(QColor(0, 0, 255), width=2.5))
        self.p2.addItem(self.HorsePowerCurve)
        self.p1.scene().addItem(self.p2)
        self.p1.showAxis('right')
        self.p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('HorsePower', color='#0000ff')
        self.p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(self.p2)
        self.p1.vb.sigResized.connect(self.updateViews)

#This is where the buttons will be set up at.
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.Print_Out)

    def Print_Out(self):

        #This gives a unique time stamp for each file made.
        outputFileName = "DynoData_#.csv"
        outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S", localtime()))

        with open(outputFileName, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
            outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
            #test = self.torque
            #test2 = self.torque , self.rpm
            outfileWrite.writerow([self.torque,self.horse_power,self.rpm,self.time])

    def updateViews(self):
        self.p2.setGeometry(self.p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
        self.p2.linkedViewChanged(self.p1.vb, self.p2.XAxis)

    def onDataChanged(self, Force, RPM, Max_RPM, Torque, Max_Torque, Horsepower, Max_Horsepower, Run_Time):
#These tell the program to display the values to the LCDs
        self.lcdNumber.display(Max_RPM)
        self.lcdNumber_2.display(Max_Torque)
        self.lcdNumber_3.display(Max_Horsepower)
        self.lcdNumber_4.display(RPM)
        self.lcdNumber_5.display(Torque)
        self.lcdNumber_6.display(Horsepower)
        self.lcdNumber_7.display(Run_Time)

        if self.counter < 50:
            self.torque.append(Torque)
            self.horse_power.append(Horsepower)
            self.time.append(Run_Time)
            self.rpm.append(RPM)
        else:
            self.torque = self.torque[1:] + [Torque]
            self.horse_power = self.horse_power[1:] + [HorsePower]
            self.time = self.time[1:] + [Run_Time]
            self.rpm = self.rpm[1:] + [RPM]
        self.HorsePowerCurve.setData(self.time, self.horse_power)
        self.TorqueCurve.setData(np.array(self.time), self.torque)
        self.updateViews()

#This is part of a standard closing script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dyno = GUI()
    Dyno.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your data is in lists, you need to form rows of each instance of data items.  One way is to transpose the lists with `zip`:

```
>>> hp = [1,2,3]
>>> rpm = [4,5,6]
>>> time = [7,8,9]
>>> for row in zip(hp,rpm,time):
...  print(row)
...
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

Note how the first item in each list is printed, then the second, etc.  You can use this to get your data into rows.  Here's a standalone example:

```
import csv

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.torque = [10,20,30]
        self.horse_power = [100,200,300]
        self.rpm = [1000,2000,3000]
        self.time = [1,2,3]

    def print(self):
        with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as outfile:
            outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile)
            outfileWrite.writerow('Torque HP RPM Time'.split())
            outfileWrite.writerows(zip(self.torque,self.horse_power,self.rpm,self.time))

t = Test()
t.print()
```

Note `writerows` (plural).  That expects a list of lists.  `writerow` (singular) expects a single list and is used for a header. Output file is:

```
Torque,HP,RPM,Time
10,100,1000,1
20,200,2000,2
30,300,3000,3
```

Comment: I was trying both the `writerow` and `writerows` individually and i noticed that they made differences to the output but not resolving anything really. Is the key here using the `zip` command. I tired that like you did in your top command but it made my data transposed from what I needed it to be. I also tried with an * but that did something else. Why does this seem to work without the for statement like you have it in your second example?

Comment: `zip` returns an iterator returning the first items from all the lists, then the second, etc.  So `writerows(zip(list1,list2,list3))` interates over the rows returned by `zip` and doesn't need a `for`.  You could also write: `for row in zip(list1,list2,list3): writerow(row)` to do them one at a time like the first example

Comment: I see, using writerows is doing the same thing as the for loop.  The writerow option sounds like it would be slower.

Answer (score -1):

First, calling a definition print in python is not recommended at all. Unless you do want to over-ride python 'print'. 'print_to_csv' for example.

As for the csv, you need to group your data into lists of [torque, horsepower, rpm, time] so your it will look like something like this,

```
data_lists = [
   [torque(0), horsepower(0), rpm(0), time(0)],
   [torque(1), horsepower(1), rpm(1), time(1)],
   ...
   [torque(n), horsepower(n), rpm(n), time(n)]
]
```

then you will loop through this data list and print your rows one by one like so,

```
for d in data_datalist:
   outfileWrite.writerow([d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3])
```

of course, many ways to structure your data, thats just an example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you're saying the reason why it isn't working is because my data isn't in the form of a list? I thought when the data was defined as `self.data = []` it makes it a list.

Comment: Your data is in a list, but its grouped incorrectly. You need to group it so that its a list of lists [ [ ], [ ], [ ],...,[ ] ]. and each of those individual lists is a complete torque, horsepower, rpm and time data sets.

Comment: So I have found something that works a little better than what I started with and I was wondering if you know anything about it. where I have `delimiter (",")` changing it to `delimter("\n")` makes a new row for each of my outputs, however the outputs are printed in rows rather than columns. Like Torque is all in the first row, not all in the same column.

Comment: That is the delimiter used for splitting cells when reading the file after it being saved. You entered "\n" which is the default text for new line, so its entering a new line after each cell. This wont work, try to read my original answer again and do the required adjustments.

Comment: to use your solution, do I just copy it into my existing code replacing :`outfileWrite.writerow((self.torque,self.horse_power,self.rpm,self.time))` by doing this i get an error. I also added the first portion where you set up the list.

Comment: Presently I have been looking into transposing the data from my attempt with delimiter. That too hasn't been a fruitful endeavor.

Comment: I was illustrating an example to you of how you should construct your data. This will not work if you copy/paste.

Comment: lol, the delimiter thing wont work. btw, are you a dyno shop? or is this just some school project?

Comment: This is a school project to make a dyno. I am trying to make a really cool GUI to go with the dyno that I designed. Coding has never been my strong suit. I can follow the logic, but when trying to get it to the langue is where i struggle the most.

Comment: So I think I have made a list of lists, however the current output is that it takes all of the values and puts them into one column, this column is organised by all of the torque values followed by all of the horsepower and so on and so forth. I feel like I am close, now I just need them to separate and go to a different column.

Comment: how does your list look now?

Comment: I did not do the down vote, and it seems to work how I initially wanted it.